# Grails. ehcache throws `Cache foo already exist` during startup

Tags: grails, apache-camel, ehcache, terracotta

Have such `ehcache` configuration:

```xml
<ehcache>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

  <terracottaConfig url="192.168.1.4:9510"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                           

  <defaultCache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      maxElementsInMemory="50"                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      eternal="false"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      timeToIdleSeconds="20"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      timeToLiveSeconds="20"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      overflowToDisk="false"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      diskPersistent="false"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

  <cache name="foo"                                                                                                                                                                                                              
         maxElementsInMemory="50000"                                                                                                                                                                                                           
         eternal="true">                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    <terracotta />                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  </cache>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

</ehcache>
```

It does not work, application just does not conntects to `terracotta` server, however during startup it throws such Exception:

```
 net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: Cache foo already exists.
```

When I enabled `ehcache` debug logs, I don't see that my `ehcache.xml` is loaded somewhere (althrough another `ehcache.xml` which sits on the classpath inside some jar file is loaded). What could be a problem?

My `grails` version is `2.1.1`, `ehcache.xml` sits on `grails-app/conf` directory.

**UPDATE 1**
One more explanation. cache named `foo` is used in `ehcache.xml` and in the code as referece (actually in Apache Camel route as to('cache://foo'). When I rename `foo` in code to `bar` (e.g. route now looks like to('cache://bar') it throws the exception that `Cache bar already exists`. So, exception comes not from `ehcache.xml` configuration file, but from code referencing that cache by name. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE 2**
Seems the exception is thrown because there are 2 places inside camel routes where `cache://foo` is referenced. When 2nd reference is reached it throws that exception. So the main question is, why `ehcache.xml` is not seen by the application on startup? It should warm up and prepare `cache://foo` for future use.

**UPDATE 3**
It apparently worked before on `grails 1.3.7`. And now it does not work on `grails 2.1.1`

Comment: I added a ticket to make it easier in Camel to explicit configure the name of the configuration file to load. That ought to help your avoid loading that other ehcache.xml file from the root classpath. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run grails with -noreloading option it works well. Must be some classpath issue.